# How should I include <link> or <style> inside <head>?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to use a Google font, which requires adding either a `<link>` or `<style>` section inside the `<head>` per the below instructions. I am using a subtheme and can modify the  section directly in `html.html.twig`, if that's the right way to do it.

However, I noticed `<head-placeholder>, <css-placeholder>`, and `<jss-placeholder>` inside `<head>` and I am wondering if those are intended to be used to insert code from somewhere else.

What's the best practice for adding to `<head>`?

[image: r]

Comment: You can't use the [@font-face](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) CSS rule? You can put this inside the .css file.

Comment: @NoSssweat hmm, not sure! Do you know why Google wouldn't specify this option in the instructions? See the image (above) that I had forgotten to paste originally.

Comment: Download the font and provide it from your server. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Loading fonts from Google acts as a CDN, and allows for more parallel downloads, so personally, I prefer to get it from Google rather than saving locally.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this question. It's an entirely valid, entirely Drupal question. But someone didn't understand it, and voted it down, without saying why. Basically bullying.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan, I've been noticing this a lot with my Drupal questions. I'm new to Drupal but a seasoned developer and Stack Exchange user. Kind of disheartening, especially as this site doesn't seem to receive the level of traffic I'd expect. As one example, how is it that there is no paragraphs-module tag? It's installed on over 150,000 sites and there are hundreds of questions about it on here. I was actually considering starting a meta discussion about all of this.

Comment: glenviewjeff please post such meta question ... I might answer it ... and let me know when you posted it ... PS: @Jaypan is so right about that downvoting also ...

Comment: @Jaypan – From a privacy point of perspective it might be better to provide the fonts yourself rather than letting Google do that. 

Comment: Fair enough. I personally keep Google in a Firefox Container so that they can't track me across sites. But that's as a user, not a developer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define a library in your theme that links to the font.

`[THEME].libraries.yml`:

```yaml
fonts:
  css:
    theme:
      # Do not include http: or https.
      # Should start with a double slash.
      //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro: { type: external }
```

This library is loaded by adding it to the theme's `[THEME].info.yml` file:

```yaml
libraries:
  - [THEME]/fonts
```

Comment: Does Drupal then inject this at `<css-placeholder>`? If not, any idea what those fields are for?

Comment: Yes it does. &nbsp;

Answer (score 3):

1. All CSS library that has been declared in `[THEME].libraries.yml`
   and loaded by the `[THEME].info.yml` will be injected into the `<css-placeholder>`.
2. All JS library that has been declared in `[THEME].libraries.yml` and
   has been loaded by the `[THEME].info.yml` will be injected into the
   `<jss-placeholder>`.
3. All JS library that has been declared in `[THEME].libraries.yml`
   with `header : true` and loaded by the `[THEME].info.yml` will be injected into the `<head-placeholder>`.

```
    js-header:
      header: true
      js:
        header.js: {}
```